# Term for continuity of a function that returns sets

Tags: continuity, terminology

Let $f$ be a function from $[0,1]$ to bounded Borel subsets of some Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Suppose $f$ satisfies the following property: for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $\delta>0$ such that

$$|t-t'|<\delta$$

implies

$$\textrm{Lebesgue}(f(t)\ominus f(t'))<\epsilon$$

where $\ominus$ denotes symmetric set difference.

This is a kind of continuity property: when $t$ and $t'$ are sufficiently close, I want $f(t)$ and $f(t')$ to also be similar.

Is there a standard term for this property?

Comment: If the values are all Borel sets of finite Lebesgue measure then this is just uniform continuity w.r.t. the metric $d(A,B)=Lebesgue (A \ominus B)\equiv \int |I_A-I_B| d Lebesgue$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy what if they are Borel sets which may have infinite Lebesgue measure?